# Brand new kittens moved prematurely

Tags: cats

My cat birthed a kitten on the couch. My friend moved it to a closet, then the mom went under the bed and had another. My friend moved it also. It still has a placenta attached.  The mom will not come out from under the bed and take care of the babies. What do I do?

This is my first litter, and her second.  She had her first litter under the bed and all was well. Should I move them all under the bed with her? There are 5 kittens total.

Answer (score 6):

Moving the kittens to the mother is worth a try, and you should make sure to give mother some space so she can relax. It is important that kittens are close to the mother, since they are unable to regulate their own body temperature, even at normal room temperature in your house there is risk they get hypothermia if mother does not warm them.

Cats have short gestation cycles, which results in mother cats prioritizing their own survival over the kittens more often than not if in a stressful situation. If mother does not feel secure, she might not nurse the kittens.

If you have a baby monitor available or can set up some other means of remote surveillance in short order, I would go that route and leave the room to mother cat and her litter for a while, only entering to provide food and water for mother cat until she has calmed down.

Keeping an eye on things is absolutely crucial at this stage though, newborn kittens are very fragile creatures and without proper care they will die very fast.

If you are not experienced, I would advise to seek advice from your vet and maybe reach out to a shelter in your area, they might be able to get you in touch with people that have experience in caring for newborn kittens if the mother refuses to do so.

[You might want to check out the KittenLady channel on YouTube for some additional information.](https://www.youtube.com/@KittenLady)